# sklearn with parallel backend sends logs/output to console instead of notebook cell output

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm using `GridSearchCV` to do some analysis for a model (same problem happens with `learning_curve` btw) and have verbose parameter set to 2. The only output I get in the notebook is some minor progress logs at seemingly arbitrary points and it just prints 'Done' when the kernel gets idle.

If I use the default value for n_jobs (1) then the output is properly shown in the notebook but with parallel processing this happens:

[image]

The detailed log is printed in the console while the kernel is running.

[image]

Is there any way to have the detailed progress log be printed in the notebook?

If there is a nicer way of getting real-time progress logs from sklearn (maybe something with tqdm), that would work too.